# Show $\{p_1(x), ..., p_m(x) \}$ is linearly dependent if $p_j(1) = 0$ for all $j$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the following problem:

> Assume $p_1, ..., p_m \in \mathbb{K}_m[x]$ are such that $\forall 1 \leq j \leq m:  p_j(1) = 0$. Prove $P = \{p_1, ..., p_m \}$ is LD.

How can one prove this? My intuition takes me to the following considerations.

$I.$ Polynomial addition for any polynomials $p_i(x) + p_j(x)$, for whatever $x$, is a sum of elements of the image of $p_i$ and $p_j$.

$II.$ $0 \in \text{Im}(p_i)$ for any $i$ (by assumption), which implies $\text{Im}(p_i)$ is a linearly dependent set.

$III.$ The union of linearly dependent subsets is linearly dependent.

I strongly feel this is connected to showing

$$ap_1 + bp_2 + ... + mp_m= 0$$

has non-trivial solutions for $a, ..., m \in \mathbb{K}$. However, linking a linear combination of $P$ to the union $\text{Im}(p_1) \cup ... \cup \text{Im}(p_m)$ is not entirely natural (or at least doesn't come/seem natural to me).

Comment: As written, then, and with the usual interpretation of $\mathbb{K}_m[x]$, it's false.  Consider, e.g., $p_i(x) = x^{i+1} - x$.

Comment: In contrast, the vector space of functions $\{ f : \mathbb{K}_m \to \mathbb{K}_m : f(1) = 0\}$ has dimension $m-1$ over $\mathbb{K}_m$, so my assumption is still that you mean that space rather than $\{ p \in \mathbb{K}_m[x] : p(1) = 0\}$ (which has vector space dimension $\infty$ over $\mathbb{K}_m$)

Comment: What do you mean with $\mathbb{K}_m$ ?